# Customizing Gnome-Terminal Colors

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have selected white-on-black color scheme for Gnome-Terminal. But it keeps using green to display executable files and uses different colored background to display some directories. How can I enforce strict "white-on-black" for all items on the screen?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

To temporary disable colors for `ls` use

```
\ls
```

or use

```
dir
```

For a permanent change you have to delete the alias for `ls`. In my case the alias is defined as

```
% alias ls
ls='ls --color=tty'
```

Therefore overwrite the alias in e.g. your `.bashrc`

```
alias ls='ls --color=never'
```

---

The "sneaky way is **;)**

1. Open `gnome-terminal`
2. Edit your profile settings via

   <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Profile Preferences</kbd>
3. Open the tab <kbd>Colors</kbd>
4. Customize your colors

   [image]

Comment: That's sneaky. :D

Comment: @muru: why "sneaky"?

Comment: @Fabby if my ls isn't colouring output, I'd be looking at options for ls, not the terminal palette.

Comment: @muru omg he means `ls` o_O

Comment: @muru:  :D :D :D  I didn't spot that either!  Good one!